# Update Database with javascript variable/ transfare javascript variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to Update my database with a variable from javascript.

This is my javascript code i want the testusersGeld variable to transfare over to php.

```
var testusersGeld = 111;

var sendUsersGeld = new XMLHttpRequest();

sendUsersGeld.open("POST", "usersGeldSenden.inc.php");
sendUsersGeld.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
sendUsersGeld.send(testusersGeld);
```

and this is my php code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$requestPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");

$object = json_decode($requestPayload);

var_dump($object);

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    require_once 'includes\dbh.inc.php';

    $query = "UPDATE users SET usersGeld='".$object."' WHERE usersName LIKE '{$_SESSION["usersName"]}'";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

    if($result)
    {   
        echo 'Data Updated';
    }else{
        echo 'Data Not Updated';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

When i var_dump than i can see the 111 but when i try to echo it out it wont work. The part of Update works when i use another variable.

Comment: Why is `$requestPayload` coming from a file? Surely it should come from the POST body? Maybe I'm just misunderstanding

Comment: $requestPayload shoud contain the testusersGeld variable witch is in the javascript file. Is that wrong? I am a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: no i dont want to pass an inpud field

Comment: that's just a small detail. the rest of the answer is relevant to your issue

Comment: When you call `sendUsersGeld.send(testusersGeld)`, you are just passing `111` into there, there's no JSON. The fact that you previously set a JSON header doesn't cause anything special to happen. On the server side `$requestPayload` should hold `111` as a string, calling `json_decode` on it is unnecessary. Make sure that [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/231316) and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/231316) error reporting are both turned on. Run `var_dump($query)` to see the literal query generated, and try running it through a SQL tool to make sure it does what you want.

Comment: @ChrisHaas `111` is valid JSON, so `json_decode` likely makes sense. What doesn't is why the OP is loading a file and not using POST data.